# Azure bot skipping conversation if user types specific string

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots

I have an issue with my azure bot. Currently, I have two different conversation selection options:

```
public enum Pizza
{
    Hawaiian = 1,
    Pepperoni,
    Cheese
};
public enum Dessert
{
    Sundae = 1,
    Brownie,
    Cookie
};
```

I've added templates so that these appear as list options in the bot conversation:

```
[Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne, "Please choose a pizza {||}", ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Auto)]
public Pizza? PizzaOptions;

[Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne, "Please choose a dessert {||}", ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Auto)]
public Dessert? DessertOptions;
```

This appears like this in the bot form:

```
.Message("Choose your pizza")
.Field(nameof(PizzaOptions))
.Message("Choose a dessert")
.Field(nameof(DessertOptions))
```

The bot works asks questions as expected, however I've noticed that if I type in "dessert" when the bot asks me to choose a pizza, the bot decides to skip ahead and ask me to choose a dessert (the reverse also happens). Is there any way to disable this skipping? 
I'm not sure what's causing this to happen. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you rename your enums to something less obvious like PizzaSelection and DessertSelection?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure what's causing this to happen.

Bot Framework Formflow has an option for the user to switch to another field while its filling out the form. You can find it in their [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#provide-guidance). This is the reason why the formflow is skipping the dessert field when the user enters pizza.

> - You can switch to another field by entering its name. (Sandwich, Length, Bread, Cheese, Toppings, and Sauce).

So when you named your field PizzaOptions and DessertOptions and user entered 'dessert' for PizzaOptions, Formflow thinks that the user wants to skip and go to the dessert field.

If you want to disable the option, name your field something the user wouldn't enter for Pizza or Dessert like

```
    [Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne, "Please choose a pizza {||}", ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Auto)]
    [Describe("Pizza")]
    public Pizza PizOption;

    [Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne, "Please choose a dessert {||}", ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Auto)]
    [Describe("Desert")]
    public Dessert? DesOption;
```

Since you are using the Describe attribute, the name DesOption and PizOption wouldn't appear for the user.

[image: Output]

Comment: Happy to help :)